# Upgraded from 8.04 to 10.04, cannot boot

Tags: boot, server, upgrade, 10.04

I upgraded an old, handed down web server with a heavily customized wordpress website from 8.04 Server LTS to 10.04 Server LTS using a guide I found on Ubuntu. This seemed to go fine. There were a few errors, but on the whole, the upgrade succeeded, and afterwards I had a working system, web site was still online, good deal.

Then I rebooted. After the reboot, I am greeted with this Error Message, on every boot:

[image]

Here is my disk information, which I got by using a linux live boot CD:

[image]

I spent 8+ hours combing through forums, google, etc yesterday trying to figure this out. I'm really at a loss. At this point, I am converting a backup of the old physical web server to a VM for a temporary website.. but this one needs to get fixed.

Comment: Alright, the problem is fixed. After spending AGES trying to re-install the MBR, GRUB, trying legacy GRUB, using 2 different kinds of boot disks that supposedly "repaired" my install, I finally found the issue. Apparently, my initial upgrade from 8.04 to 10.04 got borked somehow, and it was actually trying to boot into 8.04.. not 10.04. I ended up running an ubuntu live cd and mounting the whole file system with a chroot, and running the upgrade again. Rebooted, and BAM, everything worked.